# EditText field value is cleared when the virtual keyboard is closed with back button

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, keyboard-events

thanks for looking at this question.
This is the problem, i did an app where the user enter information on an edittext, i tested it on the emulator and on a motorola phone, after that i tested it on a samsung phone (grand prime) and to my surprise the value on the fields this time were not saved. 
What i discovered was that when the keyboard is closed in the motorola and emulator, the method -setOnFocusChangeListener- is called activated by a change of focus by having it and now not having focus on that edittext field. 
But this method is not called in the samsung phone. 
So, how can i make sure this method is called on every device? or how can i solve my problem?
Thanks.

Comment: what you want exactley?

Answer (score 1):

you can handle the back button this code;

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
      //
    }
```